# How to create a floating UI icon above items in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a script that makes a UI icon appear above some items, that rotates and scales around the player and is visible at a certain distance. I managed to make a script that does all of the above, but it suddenly started to glitch and it starts to float from the start position to the start. These are my canvas' settings that the icon is being rendered on. Could someone guide me on what I'm doing wrong and please help me, I'm a newbie at unity!
[image]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ItemIconScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image prefabUi;
    private Image uiUse;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0,0.35f,0);
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Fps_Script objPlayer;
    void Start()
    {
        uiUse = Instantiate(prefabUi, FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform).GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        uiUse.transform.position = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position + offset);

        float dist = 1 / Vector3.Distance(transform.position, objPlayer.transform.position) * 2f;
        dist = Mathf.Clamp(dist, 0.45f, 0.8f);
        if(dist >= 0.6f)
            uiUse.enabled = true;
        else
            uiUse.enabled = false;
      uiUse.transform.localScale = new Vector3(dist, dist, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use camera stacking and place the ui on a different layer.
This video should help you: https://youtu.be/OmCjPctKkjw

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Ok i will do that in the future, when i have some time, i could only answer from mobile